# I want to make all queries using SQL on Android SQLite

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I don't want to use some extra codes to insert, select, update or delete to my database on Android. I want to use SQL for all of them. Is it possible? Also, could you give me some simple examples with your answers? Because, I'm new in Android development. Thank you...

Comment: +1 to Big Joe for his comment. You need to elaborate what exactly do you want. SOme more detailed information will be good to help you out in a better way.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have any more information as to what you'd like to do? Do you mean you'd rather perform all queries as raw queries? If so, you can do it like this:

```
Cursor cursor = getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("SELECT * FROM table WHERE _id = ?", new String[] { id });
```

Comment: Actually, I develop PHP, so thanks to MySQL, I want to use SQL structure in SQLite Database, as you guess. I used it to create database and table, insert data to table but I couldn't do it for SELECT. Now, I'm trying your advice.

Comment: My code is it:

private void kayitSorgula(String ingilizce) {
  
  Veritabani vt = new Veritabani(this);
  SQLiteDatabase db = vt.getReadableDatabase();
  Cursor sonuc = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Kelimeler WHERE ingilizce=" + ingilizce, new String[] { ingilizce });
  return sonuc;
  
 }

I hope I've made myself clear. I want to return the result that I got from database in this function, but I couldn't do yet...

Comment: Firstly you're returning a Cursor instance so your method will need be private Cursor kayitSorgula(..). As for your query, you're using a prepared statement syntax so your query should be "SELECT * FROM Kelimeler WHERE ingilizce = ?, new String[] { ingilizce }" as the question mark in the query will be replaced with your string variable.